# Java-Matrix multiplication failing in loop only

Tags: java

I'm a math student writing a program to help with my research, but a small flaw is holding me up and I'm not sure what's going wrong.

In the first two calls to the power method, the computation is correct. In the loop, the first power works fine, but the matrix that is made when j=2 is a 2x2 matrix, instead of the correct one I usually get!

I'm sorry if I haven't included enough information, but the program is becoming quite large and I'm unfamiliar with conventions in CS and on SO. I appreciate any help.

```
    public Queue<OrdInt> tree(Matrix inputMatr) {
    Queue<OrdInt> holder = new LinkedList<OrdInt>();
    LinkedList<Matrix> powers = new LinkedList<Matrix>();
    powers.add(Matrix.identity(inputMatr.size));
    int Np=0;
    int j=1;

    while(!powers.contains(inputMatr.power(j)) && j<Math.pow(2, inputMatr.size)){
        powers.add(inputMatr.power(j));

        try {
            Np = (2*powers.get(j).nullspaceDim() - powers.get(j-1).nullspaceDim() - powers.get(j).matrixMultiply(inputMatr).nullspaceDim());

            System.out.println("J+1 dim: " +powers.get(j).matrixMultiply(inputMatr).size);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if(Np!=0){
            holder.offer(new OrdInt(j, Np));
        }
        j++;
    }

    return holder;
```

}

edit: by request, the code for `power` and `matrix multiply`.

```
public Matrix matrixMultiply(Matrix one) throws Exception{
    if(this.size != one.size){
        throw new Exception("Incompatible Matrices.");
    }
    Matrix total = new Matrix(this.size);

    for(int x=0; x<this.size; x++){
        for (int y=0; y<this.size; y++){
            int hold=0;
            for(int z=0; z<this.size; z++){
                hold += this.get(x,z)*one.get(z,y);
            }
            total.set(x,y,hold%2);
        }
    }
    return total;
}

public Matrix power(int power) {
    Matrix holder = this;
    if(power==0){
        return identity(this.size);
    }
    if(power==1){
        return this;
    }
    else{
        for(int x=0; x<power; x++){
            try {
                holder =holder.matrixMultiply(this);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
    return holder;
}

}
```

Comment: Is `j` supposed to be incremented (or something) in the loop?

Comment: It is. And it's incremented in a part of the loop I didn't include, just because there's some math stuff that I didn't want to confuse the issue. Thank you, but that's not it.

Comment: You may want to add some code because I feel there is not enough to go on here.  E.g. what is `inputMatr` What is `powers`? Which computation is correct?

Comment: `inputMatr` is a matrix that is imputed into this particular method. `powers` is a LinkedList of these matrices, and `power(k)` is a matrix multiplication by itself k times.

Comment: Oh! Also, I'm testing with a 3x3 matrix, so my result should be a 3x3 matrix, and it is for the first two uses of `powers`.

Comment: When you say 'the first power works fine' are you referring to `Math.pow` or `inputMatr.power`? If you are referring to your own `power` method then you'll need to post the code as part of the question. It's also worth trying to replicate the problem with fixed values passed in rather than variables in your loop.

Comment: `inputMatr.power` is currently working. However, I tried putting in the fixed values, as suggested, and it looks like something about that loop is reducing the size of the matrix? I'll keep looking at it, but if you see something that might be causing that pass it along. Thank you both so much for your ideas.

Comment: powers is 0 based? Is powers(0) ever set? Is it set to InputMatr or to the 3 by 3 identity matrix? That powers.get(j-1) is strange when j=1, and I am not sure I see so clearly where it gets set. I may be missing something, but I am trying to help all think it through.

Comment: Hi Jeremy. I put my code above, however I am setting j(0) as the identity matrix for whatever size the matrix is. Also all of the matrices are square and have entries from Z2, thus the %2 at the end of the multiplication.

Comment: So if you add powers.get(0).print() it does print the (3 by 3) identity matrix? I ask because the code we see here only checks from 1 up.

Comment: I'm playing with it, and if I call powers.get(0).print() before the try-catch block, it is the 3x3 identity. However, if I put it after the try-catch, it turns into the 2x2. I'm also updating the original code to include the entire method.

Comment: I found it! I did something stupid in the `nullspaceDim` method. Thank you so much for all your help!

Comment: Great to hear about your sucess.